# How to enable HTTPS on tomcat server for multiple applications

Tags: java, security, ssl, tomcat, tls1.2

I'm running two applications on my tomcat sevrer (one is in spring boot, second is in angular which uses the first one) now I want to enable https connections to both of my applications. I have generated the following files:

- MyDomain.cer
- MyDomain.key
- MyDomain.csr

Now I want to secure connection to my applications using TLS 1.2. 
And now I'm stuck. According to Tomcat guide i should create a keystore file to store my keys, then I should generate new key. I want to use the files I have already generated, how can I archive this?

Could you describe or redirect me to a page where I can find a step-by-step guide how to configure https on tomcat with the files I have?

Comment: Normally an application server like Tomcat is sitting behind a load balancer or at least a web server, which are also used to offload HTTPS.

Comment: in my case it is a spring boot/angular applciation on tomcat without any load balancer - its not needed since it will be availible in my local network with 2-3 users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found solution:

1. generate `jsk key`
2. put it in tomcat keystore folder (if doesnt exist, create it)
3. configure server xml to point to key storage with your generated key

more detailed instruction on `how to` can be found [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/06/13/how-to-keystore-creating-jks-file-from-existing-private-key-and-certificate/).